# Getting Values from an Enum, how to?

Tags: java, enums

I've made an enum with 2 values (id of item, exp of item)

How do I pull the exp value from the enum?

here is the enum;

```
public enum boneData {

            NORMAL_BONE(526, 5),
            BIG_BONE(532, 15),
            BABYDRAGON_BONE(534, 30),
            DRAGON_BONE(536, 72),
            DAGGONOTH_BONE(6729, 125);

            private int boneId;
            public double boneExp;

            boneData(int boneId, int boneExp) {
                    this.boneId = boneId;
                    this.boneExp = boneExp;
            }

            public int boneId() {
                    return boneId();
            }

            public int boneExp() {
                    return boneExp();
            }
    }
```

This is the method for an array;

```
   public int getExp(int id) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bonesExp.length; j++) {
                    if (bonesExp[j][0] == id)
                            return bonesExp[j][1];
            }
            return 0;
    }
```

How do I convert it to an enum, thanks!

Comment: Post your relevant code in your question. Not in pastebin. And make it understandable. What do you want to achieve? Side note: your two methods will cause an infinite recursion: boneExp() calls boneExp(), which calls boneExp(), which calls boneExp()... Oh, and classes should start with an uppercase letter: BoneData, not boneData.

Comment: return _boneId_ or _boneId()_ ?!?

Answer (score 1):

Simply call the `boneExp()` method on your enum object of interest. That's it.

```
if (bonesExp.getId() == id)
   return bonesExp.boneExp();
}
```

Or to search through the whole enum collection, use its `values()` method to return the array of all the enum items:

```
for (boneData myBone : boneData.values()) {
    if (myBone.getId() == id)
       return myBone.boneExp();
    }
}
```

---

Note that enum names like classes should begin with an upper-case letter. So better:

```
public enum BoneData {
  // ... etc
}
```

and the search:

```
public int getExp(int id) {
    for (BoneData myBone : BboneData.values()) {
        if (myBone.getId() == id)
           return myBone.boneExp();
        }
    }
    // either return a default value or throw exception here
}
```

Comment: Thanks but instead of adding 5 exp, it's adding 7 exp for normal bones and it's adding more for the different bones then specifiied, do you know why?

Comment: @user3590830 yes. You've got a bug in code not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a closer look at your method for the array

```
       " for (int j = 0; j < bonesExp.length; j++) "
```

There is no where in your declaration you would find "bonesExp" rather I noticed "boneExp"
So there is bound to be an error even if you try to call bonesExp() instead of boneExp() as you decleared.